# Using user id with other model classes

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, play-authenticate

I am using the play-authenticate plugin in my play-framework project. I want to be able to use the user ID (of the user currently logged in) from the User.java model class of the plugin.

```
    @Id
    public Long id;
```

I want to do this so that when users are creating entries in a separate model class I can store the user who has created these entries. Is there functionality in place to access this information or would I need to write an additional method in the User class to return the active user?

```
package controllers;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import models.*;
import models.User;
import play.Routes;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.Response;
import play.mvc.Http.Session;
import providers.MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider;
import providers.MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.MyLogin;
import providers.MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.MySignup;
import play.data.*;
import views.html.*;
import play.*;
import be.objectify.deadbolt.actions.Restrict;
import com.feth.play.module.pa.PlayAuthenticate;
import com.feth.play.module.pa.providers.password.UsernamePasswordAuthProvider;

public class Application extends Controller {

    /*Part of the Play-Authenticate authentication plugin for the Play Framework.*/
    public static final String FLASH_MESSAGE_KEY = "message";
    public static final String FLASH_ERROR_KEY = "error";
    public static final String USER_ROLE = "user";




    public static User getLocalUser(final Session session) {
        final User localUser = User.findByAuthUserIdentity(PlayAuthenticate
                .getUser(session));
        return localUser;
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    @Restrict(Application.USER_ROLE)
    public static Result restricted() {
        final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());
        return ok(journeyManagement.render(localUser));
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    @Restrict(Application.USER_ROLE)
    public static Result profile() {
        final User localUser = getLocalUser(session());
        return ok(profile.render(localUser));
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    public static Result login() {
        return ok(login.render(MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.LOGIN_FORM));
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    public static Result doLogin() {
        com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate.noCache(response());
        final Form<MyLogin> filledForm = MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.LOGIN_FORM
                .bindFromRequest();
        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            // User did not fill everything properly
            return badRequest(login.render(filledForm));
        } else {
            // Everything was filled
            return UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.handleLogin(ctx());
        }
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    public static Result signup() {
        return ok(signup.render(MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.SIGNUP_FORM));
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    public static Result jsRoutes() {
        return ok(
                Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
                        controllers.routes.javascript.Signup.forgotPassword()))
                .as("text/javascript");
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    public static Result doSignup() {
        com.feth.play.module.pa.controllers.Authenticate.noCache(response());
        final Form<MySignup> filledForm = MyUsernamePasswordAuthProvider.SIGNUP_FORM
                .bindFromRequest();
        if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
            // User did not fill everything properly
            return badRequest(signup.render(filledForm));
        } else {
            // Everything was filled
            // do something with your part of the form before handling the user
            // signup
            return UsernamePasswordAuthProvider.handleSignup(ctx());
        }
    }

    /*Source: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate*/
    public static String formatTimestamp(final long t) {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(t));
    }

}
```

Update:

```
package models;

import play.mvc.Http.Session;
import controllers.*;
import java.util.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.data.format.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.*;
import java.text.*;




@Entity
public class Journey extends Model { 


    public SimpleDateFormat simpleTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    public SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");


    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String start_loc;

    @Required
    public String end_loc;

    @Required
    public String participant_type;

    @Required
    public String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

    @Required
    public String time = simpleTimeFormat.format(new Date());

    @ManyToOne
    public User createUser;

    @ManyToOne
    public User modifyUser;

    public static Finder<Long,Journey> find = new Finder(
        Long.class, Journey.class
        );

    public static List<Journey> all() {
        return find.all();
    }

    public static void create(Journey journey) {
        journey.save();
    }

    public static void delete(Long id) {
        find.ref(id).delete();
    }

    public static List<Journey> searchByAddress(String address) {
        return find.where().ilike("start_loc", "%"+address+"%").findList();
    }

    public void save() {
        User logged = Application.getLocalUser(session());
        if (logged != null) {
            this.createUser = logged;
            this.modifyUser = logged;
        }
        super.save();
    }

    public void update(Object o) {
         User logged = Application.getLocalUser(session());
        if (logged != null) {
            this.modifyUser = logged;
        }
        super.update(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: In whole that code there's no any action which saves or updates any object... You don't need to show us whole controller, just action(s) where you perform mentioned operations: save/update. I think you can also easily skip the imports...

Comment: I have included the model code now where i perform the update/save. It is the lines in these methods that are throwing the errors. As session is undefined for the type Journey.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write it manualy, for an example if you have a `Book.java` model you can add field for an example `updatedBy` to identify who was editing record last time, what's more you can override `Model's` methods `save()` and `update(Object o)` to make sure, that these fields will be always updated without additional effort.

```
@Entity
public class Book extends Model {

    @Id
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    public User createUser;

    @ManyToOne
    public User modifyUser;

    public void save() {
        User logged = Application.getLocalUser(session());
        if (logged != null) {
            this.createUser = logged;
            this.modifyUser = logged;
        }
        super.save();
    }

    public void update(Object o) {
        User logged = Application.getLocalUser(session());
        if (logged != null) {
            this.modifyUser = logged;
        }
        super.update(o);
    }

    // other fields/methods
}
```

Comment: I have overridden these methods as you suggested and created a user @Required 
    public User creator; but play is throwing cannot find symbol errors with Application.getLocalUser(session());

Comment: How did you implement Play-Authenticate ? Did you follow [play-authenticate-usage sample](https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate/tree/version_0.2.1/samples/java/play-authenticate-usage) ? There is an action in `Application` controller called `getLocalUser ` did you copy it to your controller?

Comment: I have the this method in my Application.java I basically have just expanded the usage example so far in my project. I have edited my question to show the method which I have in the Application controller.

Comment: I think the problem is that the method session() is undefined in my model.

Comment: That's weird, while you are probably updating the object from Play's action - which as you know recives  session() by default.

Comment: Yeh I am quite confused about what is happening. Would it help if I uploaded my Application controller (without irrelevant methods)? I'm not really too sure why it isn't finding that method.

Comment: So i've just come back to this problem now. I redownloaded the play-authenticate-usage sample and if I try and create a book model similar to yours I get the same error regarding the session method. I must be missing something, a missing import, its odd because it recognises the getLocalUser method its just the session argument, there is no method defined for it in my models.